# How can I reproduce a song on loop?

Tags: python, loops, media-player, vlc

So I need to reproduce my song on loop using VLC. I used this code and when I play it, it only plays the song once and then the program stops. How can I fix it? Here is the code:

```
def reproduce_song():
    player = vlc.Instance()
    media_list = player.media_list_new()
    media_player = player.media_list_player_new()
    media = player.media_new("Complements//song1.mp3")
    media_list.add_media(media)
    media_player.set_media_list(media_list)
    player.vlm_set_loop("Complements//song1.mp3", True)
    media_player.play()
    time.sleep(120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
def reproduce_song():
    player = vlc.Instance()
    media_list = player.media_list_new()
    media_player = player.media_list_player_new()
    media = player.media_new("Complements//song1.mp3")
    media_list.add_media(media)
    media_player.set_media_list(media_list)
    player.vlm_set_loop("Complements//song1.mp3", True)
    media_player.play()
    time.sleep(120)

flag = True

while flag:
    reproduce_song()
    quit_input = input()
    if quit_input == "q":  # To quit your program manually.
        flag = False
```

It will make your song continue playing until you quit it.

Comment: Welcome. If you find it useful then please mark it as an answer or Upvote it

Comment: @RishabhSemwal `time.sleep(120)` is a crude tool, especially if the audio is not 2 minutes long. You would be better served checking the state of the media_player to determine whether the audio has finished or not i.e. `state = media_player.get_state()` It will be an integer between 0 and 7, with the following meanings: State 0: Nothing, 1 Opening, 2 Buffering, 3 Playing, 4 Paused, 5 Stopped, 6 Ended, 7 Error

Answer (score 0):

I believe (just checking an old project) that if you add `-1, 0` to `media_player.play()` so that it looks like this `media_player.play(-1, 0)` will make it loop forever. I can't remember exactly what the arguments mean or their requirements but it does make a track loop.

Hope I got this right, and it helps :)

Comment: By the way, this is with Pygame. I also found this site (https://www.dynamiccoding.tech/play-music-with-pygame/) which explains the `play()` parameters: first parameter is how many times it plays (-1 being forever), and the second is where the track starts from. Whether this will clash with how you are doing it, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks!! This will totally be usefull later, but right now I can only use Tkinter for this project. Thank you anyways!!